# Arranging Colored balls

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

There are 2 black balls, one red ball and one green ball. How many different linear arrangements can be generated by these balls ?

As per my understanding, the answer should be 4! * 3! (4 factorial because there are four spots that need to filled and 3 factorial because there are three distinct colors ). Is my approach correct ? or am i wrong ?

Comment: must each arrangement include all four balls ?

Comment: Are we to assume the black balls are considered the same object in the line? Also do we need all four balls in all cases?

Comment: Yes WW1 .. we need four balls in all arrangements.

Comment: @scoopfaze ... Yes i am treating black balls as same object because they have same color.. Will you treat them differently ?

Comment: Just clarifying. It wasn't explicit.

Comment: write down all arrangements for these 4 balls and count

Answer (score 2):

There are $\binom 42=6$ ways to choose positions for the two black balls.

For each of these choices, there are 2 ways to place the other two balls.

The total number of arrangements is
$$N = 2\binom 42 =12$$

Comment: Many thanks, brother...  Why 4! * 3! is wrong ? I am trying to improve my understanding .. Please help

Answer (score 1):

Treat their respective linear arrangement like letters in a four-digit word
__ __ __ __ with the letters $b$, $g$, and $r$ for black green red respectively.
There are $4*3*2*1$ spots for each letter but since there are 2 blacks we divide by $2!$ otherwise we would count $g,r,b1,b2$ and $g,r,b2,b1$ as different when they are indeed the same.

$4!/2!=12$

The answer wouldn't be $4!*3!$ because $4!$ is already counting the case of different colors (4 colors for the first spot, 3 for second...) you would instead divide by $2!$ (the number of ways the two blacks can be arranged)

Generally, questions like this can be solved with the formula
$n!/(k1!k2!...kj!)$ the number of arrangments of a word (or line) consisting of $k1$ copies of object/letter 1,$k2$ copies of 2 and so on up to $kf$ copies of letter j, with n total letters/objects.

Comment: Many thanks @Leonard …. Got your point .. Great explanation .. so basically it's BBGR … Hence, 4! divided by 2! … Have a wonderful day.

Answer (score 1):

There is a rather similar approach that includes the 4! you were thinking of:

Let's say you've got 4 balls with 4 different colors.
Then there are **4! ways to permute** those.

Back to your case:
Every single permutation has its permutation-buddy with the black balls switched.
you can't make out any difference between those two permutations.
Hence they are the same.

4!/2 = 12 possibilities

Edit: slower than @Leonard Euler

Comment: Many thanks, Fabi .. great explanation .. Have a great day